# CSS background image, content is off of the page

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use only the bottom section of an image as the background on my layout. Here is the CSS to make the image appear how I want it to.

CSS:

```
    .image{
        position: absolute;
        background-image: url("hero.jpg");
        width: 1440px;
        height: 1315px;
        top:-760px;
    }
```

So now when I put it in my html document like this any content I add is out of view because I put the -760px on the top of the image.

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>Apple</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="image">


        </div>
    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

My question is how can I use this image without having any added content appear above and off the page.

Rest of CSS:

```
body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.container{
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
}

.image{
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url("hero.jpg");
    width: 1440px;
    height: 1315px;
    top:-760px;
}
```

Comment: This might help you https://jsfiddle.net/4g2x34rf/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having a full sized container and moving it upwards using negative top value like the below:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.image {
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url("http://via.placeholder.com/1280x315");
  width: 1280px;
  height: 315px;
  top: -160px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image">


  </div>
</div>
```

**Try using background-position:** With setting the height of the image container as much as it needs to be displayed. In the below snippet, we used the `background-position: center bottom;` (it aligns the image set as background within the container to the bottom center)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.image {
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url("http://via.placeholder.com/1280x315");
  width: 1280px;
  height: 155px;  /* 315 - 160 */
  background-position: center bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image">


  </div>
</div>
```

**For learning more about background CSS properties refer:**

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp